# Deriving a new class from data.table

Tags: r, data.table

This is a minimal example of what I would like to do. I would like to create my own class based on data.table. I would like to keep most data.table functions available to users of my own class, but although computations work as I need, the tag for my derived class is dropped when using data.table syntax, as per the examples below.

```
library(data.table)
test.dt <- data.table(a=1:10, b=rep(1,10))
setattr(test.dt, "class", c("deriv", class(test.dt)))
class(test.dt)
```

Preserves "deriv" class attribute:

```
test0.dt <- copy(test.dt)
class(test0.dt)
```

"deriv" class attribute is discarded!

```
test1.dt <- test.dt[ a>=2 & a<=9 ]
class(test1.dt)
test2.dt <- test.dt[ a %between% c(2,9)]
class(test2.dt)
test3.dt <- test.dt[ 2:9 ]
class(test3.dt)
```

Is there any way of getting around this problem short of writing specialized versions of all the data.table functions that I want to retain for my derived classes? I guess I would need just wrappers on the data.table functions that explicitly copy/restore the class attribute.

It looks to me like an "unexpected" behaviour. For comparison, the code below never discards the "deriv" class attribute.

```
test.df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=rep(1,10))
class(test.df) <- c("deriv", class(test.df))
class(test.df)
test0.df <- test.df
class(test0.df)
test1.df <- test[ test.df$a>=2 & test.df$a<=9 , ]
class(test1.df)
test2.df <- test.df[ 2:9, ]
class(test2.df)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're using an older version of `data.table`. Could you post your `sessionInfo()` please?

Comment: I was using the current CRAN version 1.9.2 of data.table. I have just pulled from Github, installed and built the current development version 1.9.3, and the problem is solved. Thanks!

Comment: @PedroAphalo can you answer your question to mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `[ ]` was solved in data.table development version 1.9.3, and now that version 1.9.4 is in CRAN, the problem should not exist as long as the installed data.table package is up-to-date.

Beware, though, that `data.table::rbindlist()` continues to drop derived class attributes in data.table 1.9.4.